# How to replace text in multiple file in many folder using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have many folder
ex: folder1,folder2,folder3... about folder100

In those folder have many files
ex: 1.html,2.html,3.html,4.html...about 20.html

I want to replace some text in those all html file in all folder
but not all text i want to replace is same.
ex:(for 1.html, i want to replace ./1_files/style.css to style.css) and (for 2.html, i want to replace ./2_files/style.css to style.css)....

So i try something like this and it work well

```
Get-ChildItem "*\1.html" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    (Get-Content $_) -Replace './1_files/style.css', 'style.css' | Set-Content $_
}
Get-ChildItem "*\2.html" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    (Get-Content $_) -Replace './2_files/style.css', 'style.css' | Set-Content $_
}
Get-ChildItem "*\3.html" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    (Get-Content $_) -Replace './3_files/style.css', 'style.css' | Set-Content $_
}
Get-ChildItem "*\4.html" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    (Get-Content $_) -Replace './4_files/style.css', 'style.css' | Set-Content $_
}
```

but i have to write many of those code "*\4.html" "*\5.html" "*\6.html" ...

i try this but it do not work

```
Do { 
    $val++ 
    Write-Host $val

    $Fn = "$val.html"

    Get-ChildItem "*\$Fn" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
        (Get-Content $_) -Replace './$val_files/style.css', 'style.css' | 
            Set-Content $_
    }
} while($val -ne 100)
```

**Please show me correct way to do..loop replace**
**thanks you**

Comment: please add a sample of one of the data files you want changed and how the result should look. please add it to your Question & wrap it in code formatting so that folks can find & read it easily.

Comment: `-Replace './$val_files/style.css'` --> `-Replace "./$val_files/style.css"`. Single-quoted strings are not interpolated.

Comment: BTW, `-Recurse` is superfluous because it only works when `-Path` argument points to a folder. You could even replace `Get-ChildItem` by `Get-Item`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all your subfolders can be found inside one source folder path, you can do below to do the replacement in all those files:

```
# the path where all subfolders and html files can be found
$sourcePath = 'X:\Wherever\Your\Subfolders\Are\That\Contain\The\Html\Files'
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.html' -Recurse -File |
# filter on html files that have a numeric basename
Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '(\d+)'} | ForEach-Object {
    # construct the string to repace and escape the regex special characters
    $replace = [regex]::Escape(('./{0}_files/style.css' -f $matches[1]))
    # get the content as one single multiline string so -replace works faster
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw) -replace $replace, 'style.css' |
    Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: thanks you this work well, but can you explain to me about use of 
1. (\d+)
2. [regex]::Escape and {0} and $matches[1]
i am new in powershell

Comment: and how to convert string (3.html) to integer (3) then sub(-) 1 from it 
i try this $string = "3.html"
$integer = [int]$string-1 but not work

Comment: @rarksoca `(\d+)` means to (regex) capture 1 or more **digits** in a _$matches_ object. `[regex]::Escape()` is a method to escape characters that have special meaning in regular expressions like the dot by placing a backslash in front of that character. `{0}` is a placeholder that wil be filled in through the `-f` [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f).

Comment: @rarksoca You cannot do arithmatic on a string like `3.html`. You _CAN_ do that on the `3` by casting it to `[int]`. That is what the `$matches[1]` value stores in this case (remember the `(\d+)` regex)